# Using Request/Response in REST service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, model-view-controller

I'm currently designing a REST WVF web service in C# that will be used by an MVC website and just confused about one point. Say I have two methods with signature

```
public bool IsEmailAvailable(string email address) { ... }

public DbUser GetUser(object id) { ... }
```

Can I just keep my service interface and implementation as above? Someone has mentioned to me about designing it more like

```
public IsEmailAvailableResponse IsEmailAvailable(IsEmailAvailableRequest request) { ... }

public GetUserResponse GetUser(GetUserRequest request) { ... }
```

What are the pros and cons of implementing it each way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is someone is a clever guy. Remote interface is very important, the second version is more maintainable. You can can add additional params into Request|Response without breaking changes. This is a message based style.

As for me, even the second version is not good choice. The second version contains too concrete methods. A remote interface should be based on [**parametric polymorphism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29), so this kind of API will be stable and flexible

Thus, RESTful api should look like:

```
object Get(object request);
object Post(object request);
object Put(object request);
object Delete(object request);
etc..
```

Unfortunately, WCF doesn't support this kind of interface by default, but we can use the [Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675.aspx) instead object and get the same result.

Take a look a following article for more details: [Building RESTful Message Based Web Services with WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/712689/Building-RESTful-Message-Based-Web-Services-with-W)